# Ubuntu 13.04 returns to login screen when logging in & update problems

Tags: 13.04, login, update-manager, lightdm, gdm

In an attempt to fix the problem, I uninstalled lightdm and gdm is now the default. But I experience the same problem with gdm. When I try to reinstall lighten, I receive:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! 
lightdm
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.Ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updatea/main lighten amd64 1.6.0-ubuntu3
Something wicked happen ed resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/pool/main/1/lightdm_1.6.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb So me thing wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix missing?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is error in URL in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`,
2. Find text

   `http://us.archive.Ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updatea/main`

   And replace it with

   `http://us.archive.Ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main`
3. Run

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: When I turned on my PC, all issues were resolved. Weird.